# Pascal Pseudocode

Tags: pascal, pseudocode

I'm learning Pascal Pseudocode in school and my teacher sent me this exercise:

> Write an algorithm, in pseudocode, that, when read the name and the ages for N students, counts how many of them have more than 18 years old. Should print the name of those students.

I've writen the code until printing the counting of those students, but how should I do to print their names. Can you guys give me a tip?

**PS:** I didn't learned anything of arrays or records.

```
BEGIN
  WRITE ('Insert the number of students in the class.');
  READ (n);
  i := 1;
  WHILE i<=n DO
  BEGIN
    WRITE ('Insert the student's name');
    READ (name);
    WRITE ('Insert the student's age');
    READ (age);
    IF age > 18 THEN
      count := count + 1;
    i := i + 1;
  END;
  WRITE ('There are ',count,' students with more than 18 years.');
```

I cannot proceed from here.

Comment: When asking on Stack Overflow it's really important to be able to show **what you've tried**. We're going to be motivated to help solve your coding problem when you've demonstrated effort to solving it yourself. We're not going to be as welcoming to people who just dump homework problems here and expect us to solve them. Even skeleton code is better than nothing.

Comment: Sorry @tadman. Copying the code from the paper to here takes to long.

Comment: That's a significantly better question now. It sounds like you need an array to store the names so you can print them later.

Comment: Well. I've not learned arrays or records for now. I'll try to print the name right after the comparison. The issue is that the name will show up twice, which is quite a bummer. @tadman, sorry do tag you again. There is no other option, I guess.

Comment: You are going about this completely the wrong way, by mixing up the tasks of collecting the data and processing it to find out how many students are 18 or over.  Instead, you should read the student data into a structure (a disk file or array) and *then* process the data that's been read in.  You need to read up on both records and arrays - you are wasting your time otherwise.

Comment: It's been a while since I've done much in the way of Pascal, but it is a very forgiving, easy to learn language because it has an unusually lean syntax. [Arrays](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Array) aren't really all that complicated, so it's worth giving those a shot.

Comment: I assume that Pascal Pseudocode means no attempt is made to compile it? That makes it a little harder to find bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You had several errors, you read the variables with READ instead of with READLN and I assume that the variables you have already declared. On the other hand the if it is convenient to have closure (with END)
Finally, remember to "stop" the console so that the message can be displayed

```
program count_age;
   USES CRT;
   VAR i,age,count,n:INTEGER;
   VAR name:STRING;
BEGIN
  count :=0;
  WRITE ('Insert the number of students in the class. ');
  READLN (n);
  i := 1;
  WHILE i<=n DO
  BEGIN
    WRITE ('Insert the students name ');
    READLN (name);
    WRITE ('Insert the students age ');
    READLN (age);
    IF age > 18 THEN BEGIN
      count := count + 1;
    END;
    i := i + 1;
  WRITE ('There are ',count,' students with more than 18 years.');
  readkey;
END.
```